# Display more than 9 products on home

Tags: magento, product

I added,

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/home.phtml" category_id="16" column_count="5" }}
```

To my content in the home css page. My category, with the id 16, contains 10 products. However, only 9 products are shown on the homepage (even if the category 16 contains 12 products and more).

You can check it [here](http://fachbuecher7-24.de/).

How can I display **more than 9 products**? I want 10, 5 each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like it uses the main list template, so you need to change the settings in the Admin area. Go to `System-> Configuration->Catalog->Frontend` and change the number per page options and default.

> Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values
>   
>     Products per Page on Grid Default Value

Comment: thank you! I looked for 3 hours and did not see the forest for the trees ;-)